# Issue with the look of my JButton in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

As you can see below, in the continue button there is a border around the word "Continue". Any advice on how to sort it out or any explanation as to what is causing it?

[image]

```
    this.continueButton = new JButton("Continue");
    this.continueButton.setBounds(135, 258, 95, 25);
    this.continueButton.setForeground(new Color(17,138,203));
    this.continueButton.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    this.continueButton.addMouseListener(mmlc);
    this.continueButton.addActionListener(this);
    add(this.continueButton);

    this.exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
    this.exitButton.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    this.exitButton.setBounds(242, 258, 95, 25);
    this.exitButton.setForeground(new Color(17,138,203));
    this.exitButton.addMouseListener(mmlc);
    this.exitButton.addActionListener(this);
    add(this.exitButton);`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the button is in focus by default, you can disable the focus square painted via `jButton.setFocusPainted(false);`

Comment: Perfect, that worked thanks, I will accept it as the correct answer as soon as the website allows me too

Comment: Great, you might want to add it to the other buttons aswell, otherwise if the focus would be shifted the square would appear in the other button :)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the focus of the button,

```
jbutton.setFocusable(false);
```

Comment: This would make it impossible to push the button via the keyboard,, whereas setFocusPainted(false) allows it to remain in the keyboard navigation set.